# Technology stack for a multiple queue system

Tags: mysql, postgresql, redis

I'll describe the application I'm trying to build and the technology stack I'm thinking at the moment to know your opinion.

Users should be able to work in a list of task. These tasks are coming from an API with all the information about it: id, image urls, description, etc. The API is only available in one datacenter and in order to avoid the delay, for example in China, the tasks are stored in a queue.

So you'll have different queues depending of your country and once that you finish with your task it will be send to another queue which will write this information later on in the original datacenter

The list of task is quite huge that's why there is an API call to get the tasks(~10k rows), store it in a queue and users can work on them depending on the queue the country they are.

For this system, where you can have around 100 queues, I was thinking on redis to manage the list of tasks request(ex: get me 5k rows for China queue, write 500 rows in the write queue, etc).

The API response are coming as a list of json objects. These 10k rows for example need to be stored somewhere. Due to you need to be able to filter in this queue, MySQL isn't an option at least that I store every field of the json object as a new row. First think is a NoSQL DB but I wasn't too happy with MongoDB in the past and an API response doesn't change too much. Like I need relation tables too for other thing, I was thinking on PostgreSQL. It's a relation database and you have the ability to store json and filter by them.

What do you think? Ask me is something isn't clear

Comment: It's all not clear. If your task's structure is relatively static, then use a relational database. If it's fluid, use a schemaless database. I don't get the need for per-country queues, but I think it's irrelevant here.

Comment: Also, this question is off-topic as "primarily opinion-based". This is a Q&A site, not a discussion board.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HStore extension from PostgreSQL to store JSON, or dynamic columns from MariaDB (MySQL clone).

If you can move your persistence stack to java, then many interesting options are available: mapdb (but it requires memory and its api is changing rapidly), persistit, or mvstore (the engine behind H2).

All these would allow to store json with decent performances. I suggest you use a full text search engine like lucene to avoid searching json content in a slow way.